# Installing a linux based Python package on windows

Tags: python, windows, package

I would like to use a python package called [openMSCG](https://software.rcc.uchicago.edu/mscg/docs/index.html). My problem is that I operate on a windows machine, while the package is, as I understand, made for usage on Linux or MacOS based machines.

I have anaconda installed on my computer and when I try `conda install -c vothgroup openmscg`, I get

```
(MSCG_env) C:\Users\simon>conda install -c vothgroup openmscg
Channels:
 - conda-forge
 - anaconda
 - vothgroup
 - defaults
Platform: win-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - openmscg

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/vothgroup
  - defaults

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

I assume this is so because the installer for this package is not made for Windows machines. Is there a way to install this package on my computer without installing a Linux distribution (via DualBoot, or VirutalMachine)? Or could perhaps I use the package on a Jupyter Notebook or with Google CoLab?

Thanks!

Comment: use a docker container or WSL2 to run a linux lightweight container, where you can easily install it, installing it on windows is non-trivial, it uses gcc and make and GSL, so it needs someone to port it.

Comment: Could you point me to a post or a website where it is explained how to do this. Thank you!

Comment: [ubuntu WSL2 official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-on-wsl2-on-windows-11-with-gui-support#1-overview)